# Blender 3.3.0 Cut mesh with another mesh using knife project doesnt work! Help!

Tags: knife-tool

I just started to learn blender two days ago, so i might be wrong in may ways to use blender. So I have a geographical 3d mesh which shows a highway beyond a car tunnel. What I wanna do is cut this highway as shape of this tunnel road. And I cut most of this hightway but there are still faces of this geographical 3d mesh even ive kept clicking knife project.

I clicked this geographical mesh object first in object mode, then I changed mode to edit mode, and clicked tunnel-shape mesh while pressing ctrl key, And then I clicked knife project in mesh window.(And Yes, I set the viewport to direction where i wanna cut mesh - z top)
And then, nothing happens! I turned off blender and turned it on. But nothing works and im still trying to figure out what i did wrong and i dont know yet.

[Blender Knife Project not working](https://youtube.com/watch?v=4OJhUv-v6IM&feature=share&utm_source=EKLEiJECCKjOmKnC5IiRIQ)

I searched any body who has similar issue like me and i found this. Only difference is, a guy from this youtube video can cut mesh after he moves object to origin and i cant. only first two trials did work and nothing worked after that.

And this image is a screenshot of my current blender work. The orange line is the object which has shape of tunnel road. And if you see the pink line part, there are still some mesh which i really wanna cut using knife project but still doesnt work. Ive tried many times but the mesh in the pink line part arent cut by knife project function even other stuffs were already cut! I tried cut through in knife project and nothing works....

[image]

**Im not a english native speaker so terms that i used might be different with blender english translation , I hope you understand this.

Comment: Hi, it always helps us to see your entire screen when posting screen shots :)  
Do you have a subdivision surface modifier on the geographical mesh?  
Also, if you can share your .blend file this would help https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Psyonic Hello. Thank you for your advice. I didnt  think entire screen shot would be better cause ive never upload questions on stackexchange blender. :) and also I didnt know where to upload my .blend file and my .blend file is too big to upload(over 500 mb size...). Anyway, can you tell me where i should upload my blend file to help people to understand my situation when i ask a question next time? Thank you

Comment: You're most welcome! And welcome to the Blender community!  
See my above comment for an upload site   
You can always edit your question and add a new screenshot 

Comment: @Psyonic OMG why did i miss that. Thank you for letting me know!